# Why string to hex give me same result

Tags: javascript, hex

I want to convert string 00 to hex value 3030

```
'00'.toString('hex')
```

give me 00.

What is the right method?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"00"`?

Comment: same result isn't it?

Comment: Do you want to convert a string like "XX" to a hex like "3X3X" or to a hex like "XX" + 3030?

Comment: @Alvin Well `'00'` won't compile in Java. So it's not really the same thing.

Comment: Wrong tag... It is for javascript!

Comment: Have a [look here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-string-exercise-27.php). It may be that there isn't already inbuilt function, but there is a function on the page that does the job.

Comment: If you convert '00' to an integer it should be 0 (ignoring leading zeros). If you convert 0 (int) to hex you should get 0 (hex).

Comment: http://string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx, 00 give me 3030

Comment: This is converting the ascii representation number of each char to a hex-value - not the string itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from [this web site](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-string-exercise-27.php):

```
function ascii_to_hexa(str)
{
    var arr1 = [];
    for (var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n ++) 
    {
        var hex = Number(str.charCodeAt(n)).toString(16);
        arr1.push(hex);
    }
    return arr1.join('');
}
```